# Creating javascript animation between two divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a container that contains two main divs inside it. The container's visible area is 540px high by 1024px (meaning anything outside that container is “hidden” from view. )

I'd like to create an auto-scroll between the two main divs, inside the container, so it starts with the first div visable, waits 10 seconds and then “scrolls” down to the second div and stops, and doesn't loop back to the start.

I imagine I would have to use javascript or Jquery, as CSS3 animations would be unable to do this (due to the fact I want the animation to start once the page has loaded).  I have drawn up a basic image of what I'm looking to do but beyond that I don't know where I would start. HELP!!!

UPDATE: I have posted an updated js fiddle here using the EXTREMELY limited knowledge I have:

http://jsfiddle.net/D7Aad/16/

Currently I have a "fade" between the two slides, the idea would be that instead of fading, the page would automatically scroll down to the second div and then stop and NOT repeat.

I think my problem may lie in the javascript code:

```
var continuous = function() {
$("#slide_one").fadeToggle(600);
$("#slide_two").fadeToggle(600);   
}

setInterval(continuous,5000);
```

[image]

If there are any details that would specifically help me explain what I'm looking for, please post them in the comments, and I'll get back to you.

Comment: I hate this part.. **What have you tried?**

Comment: Perhaps you could provide the markup for your divs? Perhaps in a demo at http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: sorry about the missing information guys, I have tried doing it with CSS3 animations, but haven't had any luck (mainly due to lack of knowledge). I have updated the main question with a rough JS fiddle example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D7Aad/17/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Show both slides
    $('#slide_one, #slide_two').show();
    //Define a 2 seconds timeout before starting the animation
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('body').animate({
             //Scroll to #slide_two div
             scrollTop: $("#slide_two").offset().top
         }, 2000); // the scroll down animation will last 2 seconds
    }, 2000); // after 2 seconds, scroll down
});
```

Source: [jQuery scroll to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)